# Visual Studio 2010 Macros broken after updating to windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2010, macros, windows-10

I always used macros with Visual Studio. They are a part of my daily workflow. However, after upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 10, the macros are now broken. Whenever I try to do anything macro-related, I get the following message "The .NET assembly 'Microsoft.Vsa' could not be found.

[image]

Either I click Yes or No, the macros are disabled. I can't even access the Macro explorer.

Anyone have a clue on how to resolve this?

Comment: Does this help ? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2898975

Comment: Or possibly this one ? https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/596422/vs2010-crashes-when-trying-to-edit-a-macro

Comment: The first link is about installing .NET FW 3.5. (It's already installed, and the Microsoft.vsa.tlb file is not missing from my computer

Comment: The second link seems to be a different problem

Comment: The Visual Studio repair installation did not work. Maybe a full reinstallation would fix the problem, but the operation is quite time consuming! However, see my answer for a workaround.

Comment: @HansPassant I get this problem with every major update of Windows 10 on each of our development computers. It seems that MS voluntary removed this dll as it may be unsafe.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I searched for the missing assembly `Microsoft.Vsa.dll` in the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` folder and it was indeed missing.

However, when upgrading to Windows10, the setup creates a backup of your Windows folder, along with some program files folder. Hoping I would find the assembly in the "old" folder, I searched for `Microsoft.Vsa.dll` in `C:\Windows.old\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` and found it.

I just copied it over to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` and bingo! the macros are now working!

I'm now wondering why did Microsoft remove this assembly... Maybe because they don't support Macros since Visual Studio 2012...